# How to move jenkins email from Junk to Inbox folder?

Tags: java, email, jenkins, automation, cicd

I'm trying to set up mail (outlook 365) notification by writing script in 'jenkinsfile' once our test automation execution completes. The mail trigger script looks like below:

```
post {
     failure
     {
      script
      {
       mail (to: 'abc@xyz.com',
       subject: "Job '${env.JOB_NAME}' (${env.BUILD_NUMBER}) - failed.",
       body: "Please visit to ${env.BUILD_URL} for further details.");
      }
    }
    success
    {
      script
      {
         mail (to: 'abc@xyz.com',
         subject: "Job '${env.JOB_NAME}' (${env.BUILD_NUMBER}) - success.",
         body: "Please visit to ${env.BUILD_URL} for further details.");
      }
     }
}
```

The above script is working fine and I'm able to get the mail but it stores into 'Junk' folder. I also tried with below script after creating webhook thru Teams.

```
post {
     always {
            mail(to: 'abc@xyz.com', subject: "Pipeline Notification", body: "Job '${env.JOB_NAME} [${env.BRANCH_NAME}]' (${env.BUILD_URL})")
            office365ConnectorSend color: '#00FF00', message: "SUCCESSFUL", status: "Build 
            Success", webhookUrl: 'URL'
            cleanWs()
            }
}
```

This is too triggering email but mail is sitting into 'Junk' mail box only. 
Could you please help me how can I get the mails from jenkins pipeline (**using jenkinsfile** script, not using jenkins UI) and store it into 'Inbox' or 'Custom Folder' (i.e. created new folder called 'Jenkins' ) ?

Thanks, 
Karunagara Pandi G

Comment: This might be helpful. 
https://superuser.com/questions/878211/jenkins-email-notifications-go-to-outlook-junk-folder

Comment: i have tried to set a rule in Outlook 365 but no luck. Mail is still storing into Junk

Comment: I added sender email address into Outlook - Jun Mail options - Safe Senders list and I'm able to get the mails into Inbox.